# How to highlight current line being ran whilst program is running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

[here is a photo of my workspace [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdL3r.jpg

I am wondering if there is a setting in eclipse that will highlight and follow the line of code that is being ran when I compile a program so that I can follow it and see in real time where the code has issues. thanks!

Comment: [Debugging the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Beginner’s Guide to Quick Start Debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question,  I tried that but it only highlights 1 random line and stays like that the whole time, it doesn't move with the code.

Comment: No, there is nothing that tracks the line being executed. that would slow down execution enormously. Using the debugger you can set breakpoints, watches etc.

Comment: are there any programs that have that feature then? it will be a very big help to me .

Comment: It kind of does answer the question. if you want to watch which line is being executed you need to run your code in debugging mode and set breakpoints or use a step-by-step execution. Most lines of code take so little time executing that watching execution in real time outside debugging doesn't even make much sense.

Comment: Also note that your question to "highlight and follow the line of code that is being ran when I compile a program" doesn't even make much sense. When code is being compiled it isn't being run. Compiling code and running compiled code are 2 different processes.

Answer (score -2):

Debug can help you track which part of your code is running

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).